# What is the mathematical meaning of this question?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, problem-solving, means

> $a,b,c \in\mathbb{Z}$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then the following expression is always true:
>
> $$(x-a)(x-6)+3=(x+b)(x+c)$$
>
> Find the sum of all possible values of $b$.
>
> A) $-8$
>
> B) $-12$
>
> C) $-14$
>
> D) $-24$
>
> E) $-16$

I didn't understand what is the meaning of   *"...is always true"*.

Even though I can't understand the question, I wrote these:

$$(x-a)(x-6)+3=(x+b)(x+c) \Rightarrow x=\frac{6a-bc+3}{6+a+b+c}$$

Here, $b$ can take an infinite number of values. Or do I miss something? For example, let  random values $a=100,b=50,c=3$ then $x=\frac {151}{53}$.

Is there a problem with the question?

Comment: I think there is a problem with the question. Do you have the source of it?

Comment: Hint: Equate the coefficients of $x$.  The "are always true" means that the equality holds for every $x$ you choose.  The problem with your calculation for $x$ is that the denominator of that fraction vanishes.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Can you add more detail.. ? Thank you.

Comment: Here are a few details: $$x^2-(a+6)x+6a+3=x^2+(b+c)x+bc$$ and for this to be true for ALL values of $x$ we must have equal coefficients on both sides.

Comment: @String $6+a+b+c=0$, and $6a+3-bc=0$ ..??

Comment: @Beginner: Yes, and then you must find integer solutions and count values of $b$.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Exam question bank

Comment: The question looks like it was (badly) reworded. It should either read "... the following equation is always true" or "... the following expressions are always equal". And as others have stated, "always" is a clumsy way of implying "for all values of x".

Comment: When in doubt about a multiple-choice question; just select answer "B"!  Yes, this is based on a meta-analysis of the test environment and not the actual question - but when the question is so badly worded that indicates cost-cutting in the quality control, which contraindicates for money having been spent on randomized answer ordering.

Comment: @user376343 But this is correct..?

Comment: @user376343 $$(1/53-50)(1/53-6)+3=(1/53+100)(1/53+3)$$

Comment: @user376343  Thank you. I fixed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To answer the explicit question, "Is there a problem with the question?," the answer is Yes, it's worded in a weird, nonsensical way. (I think this is why Dr. Sonnhard Graubner left a comment asking for the question's source: was it reproduced verbatim, or did the OP paraphrase the problem?)  A better version would be something like this:

> Consider the set of triples
>   $(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{Z^3}$ for which the equation
>
> $$(x-a)(x-6)+3=(x+b)(x+c)$$
>
> holds for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Find the sum of all the $b$'s among
>   these triples.

Comment: Just a little nitpick, I think this is not strictly equivalent to the wording in the question, since if two triples have the same value of $b$ but differ in $a$ and $c$, the wording in the question would count that value of $b$ only once but your version counts it twice. Of course I don't think that impedes your point at all.

Comment: @DavidZ, excellent point!

Answer (score 10):

The question is poorly worded. It should read something like this:

> $a,b,c$ are integers such that the following equation holds for all
>   $x\in\Bbb R$:

etc.

Answer (score 6):

Two polynomials which are always equal over the reals are exactly the same.  In this case, since $x$ is allowed to vary, while $a,b,c$ are fixed, these are two polynomials in $x$.

For them to be equal, the coefficients of $x$ must also be equal.  Therefore,
\begin{align}
-a-6&=b+c\\
6a+3&=bc.
\end{align}
Now, you can solve for $a$ in the first equation and substitute into the second equation, giving
$$
6(-b-c-6)+3=bc.
$$
The problem then becomes, for which integers does this equation have a solution?

If you solve for $b$ here, you'll get a fraction in $c$, which you can study to figure out which integers for $c$ result in integers for $b$.

The problem with your solution for $x$ is that the denominator of your fraction is zero.

Comment: You forgot a "$+ 3$" on the left side of your final equation.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thanks, that's what I get for answering on my phone.

Comment: (+1) I understood.. Thank you so much. But, wouldn't it be more accurate if the question was like this?   For any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}$ the following **equality** are always true:...

Comment: @Beginner: I would have put it as "Given some $a,b,c\in \mathbb Z$ the following equality holds for all $x\in\mathbb R$ ..."

Comment: In this case, we have the right to criticize the question..

Comment: I agree that expression is not the best word.  Equality or statement would be better.  Technically, it would be ok because the equality evaluates to true or false, which is an expression.

Comment: The last equation can be rewritten as $(b+6)(c+6) = 3$ which is easier to solve for integers.